# Error with calculating rolling z score using rollify in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tibbletime

I have the following dataframe in R. I'm trying to calculate a 5 day rolling Z score (X minus its rolling mean, divided by its rolling standard deviation) by creating a function for this using `rollify`)

```
library(tibbletime)
library(tidyverse)

rolling_Z <- rollify(~((.x - mean(.x))/sd(.x)), window = 5)

data <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(19282, 19283, 19284, 19285, 
19286, 19289, 19290, 19291, 19292, 19293, 19296, 19297, 19298, 
19299, 19300, 19303), class = "Date"), `US 10 Year` = c(3.824, 
3.881, 3.881, 3.947, 3.943, 4.018, 4.01, 4.007, 4.134, 4.228, 
4.217, 4.242, 4.102, 4.003, 3.919, 3.998)), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

data %>% 
  mutate(Z_Score = rolling_Z(`US 10 Year`))
```

However I'm getting the following error. I'm guessing it is because `US 10 Year` is not the same length as the rolling mean and rolling standard deviation seeing as the first four days would be an NA. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `Z_Score = rolling_Z(`US 10 Year`)`.
x `Z_Score` must be size 16 or 1, not 64.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm not sure how tibbletime works but you can use the `zoo` package which has multiple `roll` functions.

You didn't specify whether you wanted a forward roll or a roll that took from both sides so in this case I used `rollapplyr()`

There are parameters in the zoo `roll()` function family that allow you to specify how you want to roll, whether you should allow partials, etc. and you can change these to fit your needs.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

data %>% 
  mutate(mean = rollapplyr(`US 10 Year`, 5, mean, partial = T),
         sd = rollapplyr(`US 10 Year`, 5, sd, partial = T)) %>% 
  mutate(rolling_Z = (`US 10 Year` - mean) / sd)

output ---------

   Date       `US 10 Year`  mean      sd rolling_Z
   <date>            <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 2022-10-17         3.82  3.82 NA         NA    
 2 2022-10-18         3.88  3.85  0.0403     0.707
 3 2022-10-19         3.88  3.86  0.0329     0.577
 4 2022-10-20         3.95  3.88  0.0503     1.27 
 5 2022-10-21         3.94  3.90  0.0511     0.936
 6 2022-10-24         4.02  3.93  0.0568     1.48 
 7 2022-10-25         4.01  3.96  0.0560     0.896
 8 2022-10-26         4.01  3.98  0.0368     0.598
 9 2022-10-27         4.13  4.02  0.0692     1.61 
10 2022-10-28         4.23  4.08  0.0986     1.51 
11 2022-10-31         4.22  4.12  0.107      0.911
12 2022-11-01         4.24  4.17  0.0981     0.778
13 2022-11-02         4.10  4.18  0.0625    -1.32 
14 2022-11-03         4.00  4.16  0.103     -1.51 
15 2022-11-04         3.92  4.10  0.138     -1.29 
16 2022-11-07         4.00  4.05  0.124     -0.442
```

If you wanted to make this into a function you could also do this.

```
roll_z <- function(data, x) {
  
  data %>% 
    mutate(mean = rollapplyr(x, 5, mean, partial = T),
           sd = rollapplyr(x, 5, sd, partial = T)) %>% 
    mutate(rolling_Z = (x - mean) / sd) %>% 
    pull(rolling_Z)
  
  
}

data$rolling_Z <- roll_z(data, data$`US 10 Year`)
```